# Using union in ask query (Sparql)

Tags: sparql

I have an ask query with some unions in it:

```
PREFIX foo: <http://example.com/ontologies/MyOntology.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

ask
{
  {
    <http://someiri.com> ?b ?c.
    filter(!bound(?b)).
  }
  union
  {
   ?x <http://someiri.com> ?y.
   filter(!bound(?x)).
  }
   union
  {
    ?g ?h <http://someiri.com>.
    filter(!bound(?h)).
  }
   union
  {
    <http://someiri.com> rdf:type foo:RESTEndPoint
  }
}
```

How will the ask statement treat the unions?

Will it return true if all the triples in the unions are evaluated as true?

Or it will return true if it finds at least one triple that is evaluated as true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically SPARQL ASK executes until one graph pattern is found to be true, and otherwise returns false.

Therefore if any of the UNION graph patterns find a match the ASK result is true.  If all of the UNION graph patterns fail to find a match, the ASK result is false.